# Entity Framework Type Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting two tables data using EF this way and converting it to list to pass it to a view, i am working in mvc4, but i am getting this error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EFwithMVC.Models.dc_tp_personnel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EFwithMVC.Models.bc_limsEntities>'   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EFwithMVC\EFwithMVC\Controllers\PersonellController.cs 119 34  EFwithMVC
```

Here is my code:

```
public  List<bc_limsEntities> GetTwoTableData()
    {
        using (var db = new bc_limsEntities())
        {
            return (from x in db.dc_tp_personnel.Include("dc_toutside_test")
                    where x.PersonId == 1
                    select x).ToList(); 
        }

    }
```

Kindly help me,  dont know why this error coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just by looking at your quety it obvious that what you are returning is a collection of .dc_tp_personnel object

```
 return (from x in db.dc_tp_personnel.Include("dc_toutside_test")
                        where x.PersonId == 1
                        select x).ToList();
```

but in your return type you defined  `List<bc_limsEntities>` which is the context btw, so therefore the exception you are getting is because you are retutning `dc_tp_personnel` but the return type is `bc_limsEntities` if you make return type `dc_tp_personne`l you should not get that exception